# Cannot load JDBC driver class 'com.mysql.jdbc.Driver'

Tags: tomcat

hi i am deploying my application in tomcat on linux machine bt i am getting error......
i have putted mysql-connector-java-5.1.18-bin.jar in tomcat/server/lib folder..

```
org.apache.commons.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot load JDBC driver class 'com.mysql.jdbc.Driver'
        at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createDataSource(BasicDataSource.java:766)
        at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.getConnection(BasicDataSource.java:540)
        at jdbchandler.JDBCHelp.getConnection(JDBCHelp.java:24)
        at requesthandlers.HandleLoginRequest.handleRequest(HandleLoginRequest.java:98)
        at web.Controller.doPost(Controller.java:38)
        at web.Controller.doGet(Controller.java:24)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:690)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:803)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:269)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:188)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:210)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:172)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:525)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:117)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:108)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:151)
        at org.apache.jk.server.JkCoyoteHandler.invoke(JkCoyoteHandler.java:200)
        at org.apache.jk.common.HandlerRequest.invoke(HandlerRequest.java:291)
        at org.apache.jk.common.ChannelSocket.invoke(ChannelSocket.java:775)
        at org.apache.jk.common.ChannelSocket.processConnection(ChannelSocket.java:704)
        at org.apache.jk.common.ChannelSocket$SocketConnection.runIt(ChannelSocket.java:897)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPool$ControlRunnable.run(ThreadPool.java:685)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:595)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:200)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:188)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:251)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassInternal(ClassLoader.java:319)
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:164)
        at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createDataSource(BasicDataSource.java:760)
        ... 23 more
```

plz help

Answer (score 8):

There is nothing called `tomcat/server/lib`

If it is Tomcat 5.5.x then the path should be `tomcat/common/lib`

For other versions : `tomcat/lib`

So put your jar file in correct path.

Comment: i am using linux and my tomcat diractery is opt/tomcat5.5/server/lib  there is also folder opt/tomcat5.5/common/lib. shud i put jar file here?